# How Can I Test Laravel With Table Seeders That Do Not Have A Route?

Tags: laravel, tdd, laravel-5.8

I have a table called `states` that holds all 50 US states. It has two columns, `name` and `abbr`. The seeder is working great -- all is well.

I am trying to write a Feature test to make sure that the state always has a `name` and `abbr`. Seems a bit overkill but I'm learning TDD and seems like another place to learn.

Because there will only ever be 50 states, I do not have a controller or route to create a new state. I simply call the seeder to populate the table.

My test looks like this:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use App\State;

class StatesTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_state_must_have_a_name(): void
    {
        // Persist a new state.
        $state = factory(State::class)->create([
            'name' => null,
        ]);

        // Verify that name is missing.
        $this->assertDatabaseMissing('name');  // wrong but kind of what I'm looking for
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
```

Which is absolutely correct. Just not sure how to write the test so that it passes. I'd like to have two more, one that checks for no `abbr` and then on that is a successful insert.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database does not allow for your application to become in an invalid state, so there's no way for you to test what your application does in that state. However you can test that the database does not allow for you to get in that state.

In this case I'd say it would be a good test to run the factory and test if it throws the exception you'd expect.

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_state_must_have_a_name(): void
    {
        // Persist a new state.
        $state = factory(State::class)->create([
            'name' => null,
        ]);

        // Verify that name is missing.
        $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null');
    }
```

[See phpunit docs for more info](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php).

You can do the same for `a_state_must_have_an_abbr`. Additionally you could go for a test which actually does successfully write a record with `$this->assertDatabaseHas(...)`

Comment: Thank you! This was the push in the right direction I needed. :)